# Powershell: what does "Supply values for the following parameters / Input Object" mean?

Tags: powershell, export

I am currently trying to export a list of AD-Users per every AD-Group, which starts with "AD-AllowMailbox*"

Since there are more than 200+ AD-Groups like this (AD-AllowMailbox-Parking, AD-AllowMailbox-Office..) I prefer to do this with a single script.

The powershell code I am using is:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter '(Name -like "AD-AllowMailbox-*")' | 
    ForEach-Object {Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive -Identity $_} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name' |
    Sort-Object -Unique
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Users\Admin\mailbox.csv
```

The script runs. However, I get the following message in powershell:

```
cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:
```

What does this mean and why does it pop up? No matter what value I insert as input, I get an empty .csv.

Am I missing something in the script?

Comment: you're missing a pipe after the `Sort-Object` statement :) `Sort-Object -Unique |`

Comment: Forgot pipe (`|`) after `Sort-Object -Unique`, pipe means to send output of (left) to input of (right)

Comment: It's always the little simple things in the code... :) Thank you very much. It worked 

Comment: Also, as you have a list of strings, the .CSV is a strange choice. `Out-File` will be more correct in this case

Comment: @filimonic thanks! I was just wondering if .csv is a good idea, because the output didn't look quite well. Out-File was definitely the better solution.